# Does Javascript have a way to do "in" when I want to see if a value is one of many?

Tags: javascript

My code looks like this:

```
if (testStatusId == 4 || testStatusId == 5) {
```

This is just a simplified version for the question.

Does Javascript have anything like an "in" where I would not need to repeat testStatusId for every number check?

Comment: linq.js in a good library to use for operating on Arrays. https://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make an array like:

```
if([4,5].includes(testStatusId)) { ... }
```

You'll need a polyfill for it as it's not universally supported. (ex: https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-includes-polyfill)

You could use indexOf with the same approach with wider compatibility:

```
if([4,5].indexOf(testStatusId) !== -1) { ... }
```

Comment: adding my solution to yours through an edit. how annoying.

Comment: @PatrickMotard I didn't see you posted the same until I was done editing. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
var j = [4,5];
if(j.indexOf(testStatusId) !== -1){
//your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (testStatusId)
{
       case 4:
       case 5:
          // do whatever
          break;

       case 6:
          // something else
          break;

       default:
          // everything else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
if([4,5].indexOf(testStatusId) !== -1) {
}
```

Although the code you have is probably already the best, if they is only two numbers.

Comment: duplicate of two other answers now :)

Comment: oh, you guys are fast.