# If getValue equals this or that

Tags: javascript

How do I getValue of multiples? So if equals this or that?

I've tried this and it doesn't act as I expect.

```
range.getValue() == "Yes" || "No" || "Repeat"
```

Basically I want to avoid this

```
if (sheet.getName() == sheetToWatch && range.getColumn() == purchasedColumn && range.getValue() == "Yes") {
    copyRow();
} else if (sheet.getName() == sheetToWatch && range.getColumn() == purchasedColumn && range.getValue() == "No") {
    copyRow();
} else if (sheet.getName() == sheetToWatch && range.getColumn() == purchasedColumn && range.getValue() == "Repeat") {
    copyRow();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Javascript have a way to do "in" when I want to see if a value is one of many?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098064/does-javascript-have-a-way-to-do-in-when-i-want-to-see-if-a-value-is-one-of-ma)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function isIn(x, a) {
  return a.indexOf(x) > -1;
}

if (sheet.getName() == sheetToWatch 
    && range.getColumn() == purchasedColumn 
    && isIn(range.getValue(), ["Yes", "No", "Repeat"])) {
  copyRow();
}
```

isIn takes a value and an array of possible values and checks if the value is in the array.

Of course you could also put the indexOf in the condition.